# Jquery event for changing an element's class attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to execute a JQuery code when an element's class attribute is changed. For example, initially the element will be : `<div class="my-class">`. So, when a new class is added to this div, (i.e. `<div class="my-class new-class">`, I have to trigger a JQuery code.

How do I do this in JQuery? Is there event for attribute change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have absolutely no means of telling when the external function changes the class (like, a custom event, for example), you will have to do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Cache the required element
    window.elementInQuestion = $('#element-that-changes-class');

    function checkClass(){
        if (window.elementInQuestion.hasClass('new-class')) {
            // Trigger a custom event
            $(document).trigger('elementHasClass');

            // If you need the check only until the first time the class appears
            // you can cancel further checks here
            clearInterval(window.classCheckerInterval);
        }
    }

    // Check if an element has class every once in a while
    window.classCheckerInterval = setInterval(checkClass, 100);

    $(document).bind('elementHasClass', function(){
        // Your handler here
    });
});
```

Comment: the solution worked. but the line if (window.elementInQuestion.hasClass('new-class')) only works when I change it to if ($('#element-that-changes-class').hasClass('new-class'))

Answer (score 0):

Cant' you just bind the functionality to the function that changes the class?

Comment: I can't. Because the CSS attribute is changed by an external JS function on which I don't have any control.

Comment: How external? Can you provide more info?

Comment: I'm trying to enhance the SERPs that Google CSE returns. So, in this case, Google's JS is modifying the element's attributes. When they modify an attribute, I need to call my JS.

Answer (score 0):

There is no cross browser node changed event.

One option could be to use the [LiveQuery](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery/) plugin. It will scan the dom periodically looking for changes and will raise an event if it encounters a change.